# Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых нет ни одной буквы E и при этом не менее трёх букв A

Tags: python

**Помогите пожайлуста ,не понимаю как сделать **[с решу егэ](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=40999)

[image: введите сюда код]`

Comment: Делишь на подстроки по `E`, фильтруешь те, в которых есть три `A`, считаешь их длины, берёшь максимум. В чём проблема-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ты неправильно прочитал условия задачи и что от тебя требуется, потому что не вижу у тебя в коде проверку длины строки

Вот мое решение, уверен есть более элегантное решение этой задачи, но думаю это самое понятное

```
with open('24.txt', 'r') as f:
    letters = f.readline()

letters = letters.split('E')  # Разбиваем строку по букве E

length = 0  # Здесь будет храниться максимальная длина строки в которой нет буквы E и есть три буквы А

for string in letters:  # Проходимся по строкам, который получились после разбития по букве E
    if string.count('A') >= 3 and len(string) > length:  # Проверяем исходя из условий задачи
        length = len(string)

print(length)
```

Comment: Не следует отвечать на вопросы, нарушающие правила сайта.

Comment: такое нельзя спрашивать ?

Comment: не такое, а _так_. посмотрите причину закрытия вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

```py
f = open("24.txt") # открываем файл, можно как вы с помощью контекстногоменеджера, но в рамках егэ не имеет значение
s = f.readline() # считываем строку(она одна единственная)
lst = s.split("E") # разделяем строку по символу Е(символ Е пропадает)
# например было ASDSAEASDA станет ['ASDSA', 'ASDA']

# выкидываем где А меньше 3
new_lst = []
for x in lst:
  if x.count("A") > 3:
    new_lst.append(x)
# можно проще, но сложнее в понимании
# new_lst = filter(lambda x: x.count("A") > 3, lst)

# находим максимальную
mx = 0
for x in new_lst:
  mx = max(mx, len(x))
print(mx)
# или проще
# mx = max(new_lst, key=len)
# print(len(mx))
```

Comment: Не следует отвечать на вопросы, нарушающие правила сайта.